# Shape not shown

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I have an AutoCompleTextView for which I created a shape which creates a nice border around the TextView. On my Tablet, I can see the border. With the excact same configuration, I can't see it on my phone. So... What am I missing?

Here's my AutoCompleteTextView:

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id='@+id/search'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        android:layout_width='fill_parent'
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_picture"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:hint="search..."
        xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

And here's the Shape back.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/blue"/>
   <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
</shape>
```

I found the Shape on Stackoverflow and works usually perfectly.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//this will work fine if your remove the `'` symbol and put ""

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_picture"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:hint="search..."
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

//in my htc wildfire 2.3 it looks fine

[image]

//actually I removed the line `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_picture"`
as I am using Linear layout.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the characters. It still doesn't work on the phone, works as usual on the tablet. So the mistake must be somewhere else...

Comment: increase width of the stroke to check. and remove the padding also.

Comment: for me its working fine. I changed only the color/blue to FF0000.

Comment: I created a new project and guess what - it works fine :-)! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

solved this thing!

I use themes. I defined:

```
<item name='android:windowBackground'>@color/transparent</item>
```

appearently, this was the cause of the problem. I deleted this  and now it works just fine. I don't quiet understand how, but hey... it works.